# How to get rid of arrows from european voltage source in tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz

I would like to get rid of the arrow from the voltage source and just use the label without arrow. Is it posible? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
        \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.cm}
         \begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.6]
                \draw (-2,-2) node[ground] {} to[sV=$SG_1$] (-2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *seems* to me that all you need is `sinusoidal voltage source,label=...`, which can be made a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.cm}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.6]
 \draw (-2,-2) node[ground] {} 
    to[sinusoidal voltage source,label=$SG_1$] (-2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\quad\tikzset{myV/.style={sinusoidal voltage source,label=#1}}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.6]
 \draw (-2,-2) node[ground] {} 
    to[myV=$SG_1$] (-2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can just add a `\node` at some place, that doesn't print the arrow, but you get the label placed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[t!]
  \centering
  \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.cm}
   \begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.6]
     \draw (-2,-2) node[ground] {} to[sV] (-2,0);
     \node[anchor=east] at (-2.5,-1) {$SG_1$};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Skillmon, I have so many voltage sources in the diagram, and to add nodes at each source is really time-consuming. Are there any other alternative options similar to labelling?